# CMS app not loading javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I'm building a forum app, and uses the LTR theme for CMS and Codeigniter as framework. When i got to my dashboard all layouts are loaded ok. My pages are linked using ajax via Accordion, on first click on (add_forum) page the CKEditor loaded perfectly but when I click it again the theme/CKEditor doesn't load or work any more.

I have this javascript on my dashboard page

```
<!-- Global stylesheets -->
<link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/minified/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/minified/core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/minified/components.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/minified/colors.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- /global stylesheets -->

<!-- Modiefied CSS -->
<link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Modiefied CSS -->

<!-- Core JS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js"></script>
<!-- /core JS files -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/core/app.js"></script>
```

And this javascript on my add_forum page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/core/libraries/jquery_ui/interactions.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/forms/selects/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/pages/form_select2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/pages/editor_ckeditor.js"></script>-->
```

and this is my ajax function

```
function contents($data) {
  $contents_view = $data;
  $.ajax({
    mimeType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8', // ! Need set mimeType only when run from local file
    url: '<?=base_url();?>forums/' + $contents_view,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#contents-view').html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
    },
    dataType: "html",
    async: false
  });
}
```

Hope you can help me.

when i first click the add_forum link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9QMf.jpg)

When i click it again the result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHwyE.jpg)

Same result with other link/pages. The theme is not loading, only on first load of the whole page

Comment: any errors coming up in the console?

Comment: There are no errors...